# AWS: What does "may use content to improve the service" mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services

As per this page, Amazon may use my content.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/easily-manage-content-policies-ai-services-aws-organizations/

> Certain services (Amazon CodeGuru Profiler, Amazon Comprehend, Amazon
> Lex, Amazon Polly, Amazon Rekognition, Amazon Textract, Amazon
> Transcribe, and Amazon Translate) may use content to improve the
> service.

Does the word "content" mean the S3 files? Or does it mean the files from EC2 instance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks a legal opinion.

Comment: Those all appear to be services that take "input" from users (eg code, text, voice, images). Thus, it would likely be referring to the data provided when an API call is made to those services.